# Scripts from CDN not loading in iframe created dynamically in a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, iframe, android, chrome

In a lightening component, I am dynamically creating and adding an iframe like this -

```
$A.createComponent(
      'iframe',
      {
        'aura:id': 'iframe',
        src: iframeUrl,
      },
      function(createdIframe, status) {
         if (status === 'SUCCESS') {
          var body = component.get('v.body');
          body.push(createdIframe);
          component.set('v.body', body);
         }
      }
)
```

The iframe is getting added by this. In the iframe i am loading a webpage in which i am fetching some js files from a CDN, and am rendering the page using those files.

This is working fine in 
Desktop Chrome,
Android Chrome, 
iOS Chrome, 
Salesforce iOS App

But it is not working in Salesforce Android App.

I added some debug logs and found that `onerror` of the script tags loading files from CDN is being called, and they are not loading.

Any ideas on why this could be? Or how can i debug this further? 
As the issue is coming only in Salesforce Android App, its difficult to debug.

Please help.